# PostgreSQL - checking if restored database has all the data as original

Tags: postgresql

I backup my PostgreSQL database once a week. One time, during the restore, the restored database was 2.9GB in size, while original database size was 3.7GB. The reason for different sizes is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29236005/postgresql-restored-database-smaller-than-original) and that's not a problem.

I back up database using:

```
pg_dump -U postgres database_name -f backup_file.sql.
```

To restore the database I use:

```
psql -U postgres -d target_database -f backup_file.sql.
```

My question is what is the best way to test and ensure that the restored database has all the data from original database?

Comment: How deep would you define all the data? Just number of lines per table or deeper?

Comment: @frlan   I am looking to chose between the best options. What options can you suggest?

Comment: If pg_restore finished successfully (that is: you got no error), you can be sure that everything that was in the dump, is now in the target database. Consequently if pg_dump succeeded without errors you can be sure that everything you asked for is in the dump. The only possible reason why the restored database would not contain the expected data (even without an error) is that you did not specify the correct parameters for pg_dump.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name    I back up database using:  pg_dump -U postgres database_name -f backup_file.sql. To restore the database I use: psql -U postgres -d target_database -f backup_file.sql. Using this approach where I can find log file, if any, with messages during restore?

Comment: I met similar problems today, have you found the solution to this problem?